# Can't Get Python to Run on WAMP Server

Tags: php, python, apache

I am frustrated right now as I have been battling with how to get this to work but no solution that I have followed so far are able to rescue me. I have followed this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266153/how-to-install-python-with-wampserver) but it is still a futile effort. When I run `index.py` it says **Unable to connect***. This is the third day.

Just switching from PHP to Python. Have reinstalled [Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/) and WAMP server afresh after all the tweaking and would like someone to help me on how to get this to work in any simple way possible.

Comment: Upvote for frustration flowing from this question all over the place

Comment: Did you install `mod_cgi` for Apache to run Python as `CGI` or `mod_wsgi` to run Python as `WSGI` (for example to use `Django` or `Flask` framework) ?

Comment: I actually configured the way it was suggested on the SO answer I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You mean first answer or second ? If second so you have WSGI. Do you know how to write WSGI python scripts ?

Comment: @furas: The second one.

Comment: Can you connect with `http://localhost/` ? Have you try `http://localhost:8090/` - because there is line in config with port 8090. Have you try `http://localhost:8090/myapp`

Comment: @furas: Yes but `http://localhost:8090/` won't connect. And `http://localhost:8090/myapp` won't connect either.

Comment: Is `http://localhost/` working ?

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly. I run my PHP file there and it works well.

Comment: OK, so Apache is running. Have you try `http://localhost:8090/myapp` ?