# configure apache for python in windows

Tags: python, wamp

I installed python27 , and also the latest version of apache.

in order to run a simple program by refering [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)

also edited the httpd.conf file also

but i accessed the folder localhost/cgi-bin displays the error 
"Forbiden you don't have the permission to access this folder"

Changed the folder permission from properties of folder.

any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Python with Wampserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266153/how-to-install-python-with-wampserver)

Answer (score -1):

So you have a cgi script named `hello.py` containing the code from the tutorial and installed in the cgi-bin directory as configured in the httpd.conf file?

If you browse to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/` you will most likely see a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response with text along the lines of:

```
You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/ on this server.
```

You need to execute the actual cgi script, not the containing directory, so try browsing to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py`.

If that doesn't work, what changes did you make to `httpd.conf`? Have you installed the cgi script in the directory specified in the `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/` directive?

Comment: The **W** in WAMP stands for Windows!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly: good point, thanks for pointing that out! The title is also a bit of a giveaway, but then again, the tutorial that OP links to is for Linux, so not sure that it's worth a down vote. Some of what I said is still applicable such as accessing the URL of the CGI script instead of the folder, so I have removed the *nix bits.

Comment: Well, not actually as WAMPServer is not configured with CGI turned on.