# How to get mod_wsgi for using Python on Wamp server

Tags: php, python, wamp, mod-wsgi

I know this has been asked and answered a few times before but the link for downloading mod_wsgi appears to have been changed. [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) There's no longer a .so file listed as 2.7 and instead they're all .whl files. I've tried downloading a couple and installing the wheel in the command line but nothing is happening. Has anyone any instructions for this?

Comment: `pip install filename.whl`

Comment: This seems to have a fairly comprehensive answer and a different link to the location of mod_wsgi downloads. That link also describes very well some of the pitfalls of mixing and matching Apache and Python versions compiled with different compilers. For reference Apache in WAMPServer is the ApacheLounge compiled versions of Apache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266153/how-to-install-python-with-wampserver