# Which mod_wsgi Binary to download?

Tags: python, wamp, wsgi

1) I am trying to setup a `WAMPServer` and am stuck on which file I need to download from the site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

I am using: `Windows 7(64 bit)`, `Apache 2.4.9` and `Python 2.7`.

2) Also, many of the tutorials I have seen on the matter say to download a `.so` file. However the above link contains `.whl` files?

I've been using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20128269/2268507 as a guide.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on these two matters.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `.so` files are shared libraries on several Unix-family operating systems. The docs you're working from were presumably written for one of those.

Comment: (on a different note -- this very much smells like a request to find an off-site resource -- a subject explicitly off-topic on SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page on the gohike site tells you to go read:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/master/win32/README.rst

Did you do that?

That page for mod_wsgi explains what version you should use for what. It does this in reference to the binaries that the mod_wsgi downloads list has, but if you understand what Python wheels are then you can use those from the gohike site as well.

---

UPDATE

Note that details at this URL are obsolete. You should use `pip install` as described at:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Once installed, run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to display config you should add to your Apache configuration file to load mod_wsgi that you installed using `pip install`.

Comment: Thanks Graham. It seems there isn't a `mod_wsgi` for my current setup. Your article did mention that `Apache24-win64-VC10/modules/mod_wsgi-py27-VC9.so` could be tried. However, I haven't been able to find this file in the `.zip` file I download from `Apache Lounge` `(http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/)` - `httpd-2.4.12-win64.zip`. I only want to use this setup to test my code locally. In light of that, is there anything you would recommend?

Comment: Where are you looking? The mod_wsgi downloads are at https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases and not the Apache Lounge site. You need to look down for latest Windows binaries. RIght now is https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases/tag/4.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read the Graham's [Git] and take a look at paragraph:
"
Note that Apache Lounge never made available any Win64 VC9 binaries for Apache 2.4. This means that technically there is no combination available for correctly running mod_wsgi with a Win64 VC9 version of Python 2.6 or 2.7.

History shows that users simply don't want to accept this and don't want to understand that mixing VC9 and VC10 binaries are not guaranteed to work.
"

See that? don't use Python 2.6 or 2.7 in Win64, Apache doesn't support the module for you.

But you can still download the ".so" file in [here](http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/folder.asp?eid=33&folder=%2Fdownload%2Fapache%2Fmod_wsgi-windows-4.4.6%2Fmod_wsgi-windows-4.4.6%2Fapache24-win64-vc10%2Fmodules%2F) , just found which is the best and suit for you and install it into Apache. [This is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOkXG0jL_8U) the tutorial how to install mod_wsig to Apache and XAMPP. Good Luck!

Rian Hariadi, Jakarta Coding

Comment: I was unable to start Apache with an .so file taken from "grapevine.dyndns-ip.com". Apache failed on start with "%1 is not a Win32 application".