# Running Python on localhost under WAMPSERVER

Tags: python, wampserver

I've researched this on Stackoverflow and other sites but I can't get it to work. I have WAMPSERVER 3.2.3 ruuning under Win10 on my desktop PC; PHP version 7.3.21, MySQL 5.7.31 and Apache 2.4.26. WAMPSERVER is installed on the C: drive in c:\wamp64, localhost is H:\sites.web. I've installed Python under C:\Python3.9 and I can use it from the command line. I downloaded mod_wsgi-4.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64. whl and installed it using pip but didn't end up with a mod_wsgi.so file. I made the following changes to the Apache http.conf file

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted <- changed to granted from denied
</Directory>
```

added +ExecCGI to this line

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +ExecCGI
```

and added .py to this line

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

as per this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3XfGXi4ifE

But when I come to running a python script under localhost it doesn't work. Am I missing something? I get an error message that I don't have permsision to run that script.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Does your Apache process have C:\Python3.9 in its PATH?  It needs to be able to find the interpreter.  Have you added it to the global PATH?

Comment: Yes, C:\Python3.9 is included in the PATH. I tried a sample file from the python install beer.py; it runs in a quickly opened and closed dos window when I click on it. I copied it to a directory in localhost and tried to execute it from a browser and got "You don't have permission to access this resource." The first line (the shebang line apparently) of beer.py is #!/usr/bin/env python3, should it be different when executed from a browser?

Comment: Or should python be installed in c:\wamp64\bin along with the php, mysql and apache executables?

Comment: My apache error log says [cgi:error] [pid 6176:tid 1252] [client 127.0.0.1:50408] AH02809: Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: H:/sites.web/pythonTest/beer.py, referer: http://localhost/pythonTest/

Comment: Well, then, you'd better turn it on.  ;)   You can put Options ExecCGI in the .htaccess file in that folder.  The #! lines are ignored on Windows.

Comment: Hi Tim, Tried that earlier today and got the follwoing error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: The apache error log says [Thu Mar 04 22:12:13.100890 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 16736:tid 1260] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:59409] couldn't create child process: 720002: beer.py
[Thu Mar 04 22:12:13.100890 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 16736:tid 1260] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:59409] AH01223: couldn't spawn child process: H:/sites.web/pythonTest/beer.py

Comment: You have AllowOverride off here, which means you can't put options in cgi-bin..  HOWEVER, the error says you're trying to run pythonTest/beer.py.  That's not in cgi-bin.  What URL are you trying to look at?

Comment: H:/sites.web is my localhost, so the URL I'm entering is localhost/pythonTest/beer.py

Comment: OK, but then you have to have a specific section in your http.conf file that configures the pythonTest directory.  The section you quoted above is for cgi-bin, which has nothing to do with pythonTest.  You COULD have a section for your root, which gets inherited by the subdirectories.

Comment: Pos DUP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266153/how-to-install-python-with-wampserver

Comment: Hi Tim, to be honest I don't understand what you are telling me to do, what does this section for the root look like? Thanks

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, I don't think this is a duplication of the other post, that post was made 9 years ago and from what I can see the instructions for getting Python running under Wampserver have changed, I saw the post you refered to and tried everything in it but still can't get it to work.